# How do I find out, within an if statement, if an object type or a property of an object within the List exists?

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to allow the player of my game to select a target to attack when in the battle scenario.

I'd like to determine if, within my List, there is a Character which is of the type Enemy (this is a class, nested within the Character class).

I would then like to be able to use that targeted character, to pass into another method I have called MakeAttack(Character pAttacker, Character pDefender).

I've been doing quite a bit of googling to try to figure out what I'm missing and am struggling to find the answer.

```
public void SelectTarget()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < currentCharactersInBattle.Count; i++)
            {
                if (currentCharactersInBattle[i] = /Enemy enemy/);
                    //this text is just to present the option to the player, the rest of the logic will be figured out later
                    Console.Write(i + ". " + enemy.Name);
            }
        }
```

Please let me know what you think.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you seem to look for something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator or this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns

Comment: Can you post a copy of the class represented by `currentCharactersInBattle` and clearly define the difference between enemy/non-enemy?  In other words, if enemy is defined by team the Team roster variable, if by character types enum or class type / hierarchy mapping of enemies, etc.

Comment: MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace has the right of it. I was looking for the 'is' operator. Thanks a lot. Now I've figured out how to implement it